# mean stack help:TypeError: cars is not a function

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, mean

I am starting to build a mean stack appliction, and when I run my app with the command:
`npm app.js` I get this:

> error:TypeError: cars is not a function

I'm install all the relevant modules with the `command:npm install @type`,

This is my code:

```
//importing modules
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cars = require('cars');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var app =express();
const route = require('./routes/route');

//port number
const port=3000;

//adding middleware - cars
 app.use(cars());

//body - parser
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
//routes
app.use('/api',route);

//testing server
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
   res.send('Welcome to port 3000!');
});

app.listen(port,()=>{
  console.log('server started at port:'+ port)
});
```

i dont know what i need to do,its seems that i have a problem with the cars modules,please help me,thank you!

Comment: You should probably use `node app.js` to start the application. Also, to install NPM packages, use `npm i --save ThePackage`

Comment: Are you trying to use CORS middleware?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question eypecially the formatting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help so it's easier to understand what your problem is

Comment: Also try to resarch a bit more what the problem is. You have an error message, that's a good start. It's telling you `cars is not a function`, try to understand what that means and why this error happens.

Comment: You should show us what you are exporting from `cars`. It's hard to know what wrong without seeing what `cars` is. It also look strange that you are calling the function as you pass it in to `app.use`. You don't typically do that with middleware.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that's not necessarily true; the module could give you a function that when executed (e.g. with some initial parameters) gives you back the middleware function to be passed to `app.use`. For example the npm package `body-parser` can be used like this `app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))`. Nevertheless OPs problem definitely stems from that attempt to execute `car` as a function.

Comment: @luke-codewalker I know your *could* do that, that's why I wrote "don't typically do that".

Comment: @MarkMeyer we might be misunderstanding each other regarding the meaning of _typical_. I've been using `bodyParser` a lot lately and so executing a function inside `app.use` to me is something I _typically do_ in the sense that it's legitimate code I use often. I just wanted to add that perspective not lecture anyone, maybe that didn't come out right :)